# Which code is better in terms of readability and performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, asynchronous, fetch

So which style of code is performance wise and in terms of readability?

```
async function fetch(){
    const url = "https//foo.com";
    const request = await fetch(url);

    // or
   
   const request1 = await fetch("https//foo.com")

}
```

Comment: if URL is either too long or used multiple times then first approach is correct or else you can choose either one of them... URLs should be in config instead of using directly

Comment: There is no measurable difference,  if any

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first one is more maintainable. Although it is better to have the URL as a separate constant in a file and use it at multiple places.

The second one is more readable in the sense you can see everything at the same place and process it easily.

I would prefer the first one for all enterprise-grade applications.